# Facebook SDK 4 - Session has expired, or is not valid for this app

Tags: facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0

Am trying to make a php page that capture the user token then retrieve data from the api, everything was working well until i manually removed the app access from the facebook account i was testing on, now its giving me an error, mentioned in the title.

Here is my code:

```
<?php

session_start();

require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookSession.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRequest.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookResponse.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookSDKException.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRequestException.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookAuthorizationException.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/GraphObject.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/GraphUser.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/GraphSessionInfo.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/Entities/AccessToken.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookHttpable.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookCurl.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookCurlHttpClient.php' );


use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
use Facebook\GraphObject;
use Facebook\GraphUser;
use Facebook\GraphSessionInfo;
use Facebook\Entities\AccessToken;
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookHttpable;
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookCurl;
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookCurlHttpClient;


$id = '';
$secret = '';

FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication($id, $secret);

$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper('http://localhost/facebook/index.php');


try{
$session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
}catch(Exception $e)
{

}

if(isset($_SESSION['token'])){

$session = new FacebookSession($_SESSION['token']);
try{
$session->Validate($id, $secret);
}catch(FacebookAuthorizationException $e){
$session = '';
}

}

if(isset($session)){
$_SESSION['token'] = $session->getToken();
echo "Login Successful<br>";
$request = new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', '/me');
$response = $request->execute();
$name = $response->getGraphObject()->asArray();
echo '<pre>' . print_r( $name , 1 ) . '</pre>';
echo '<a href="' . $helper->getLogoutUrl( $session, 'localhost/facebook/logout.php' ) .           '">Logout</a>';

}
else
{
$permissions = array('email','user_friends');
echo '<a href="' . $helper->getLoginUrl($permissions) . '">Login With Facebook</a>';

}
?>
```

Comment: Are you using an access token which you stored, and which was generated for a different app ID? the error implies that you are

Comment: If you removed the app from that account, why would you expect the token to still work?

Comment: Yes i was storing it, and i removed the app because i've updated the app permissions.

Answer (score 0):

*Solution by OP.*

Solved the problem by replacing a portion of the code with this:

```
if (isset($_SESSION) && isset($_SESSION['fb_token'])) {
    $session = new FacebookSession($_SESSION['fb_token']);
    try {
        if (!$session->validate()) {
            $session = null;
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $session = null;
    }
} else {
    try {
        $session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
    } catch (FacebookRequestException $ex) {
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        echo $ex->message;
    }
}
```